# How to fix yum update of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, yum

I run Amazon AMI EC2 instances.  One of the regular tasks is doing a yum update.  Normally, this is not an issue.  One of the machines runs Jenkins.  I tried to do the standard yum update I always do, and I got an error:

```
Error: Package: jenkins-2.306-1.1.noarch (jenkins)
           Requires: daemonize
```

I have been investigating this and it seems that this new requirement is very deprecated.  I was able to find the source, which hasn't been updated since 2016.  The current Jenkins running on that machine seems fine w/o it.  Installing the daemonize product from the old source didn't help on a copy of the machine.  It still failed on yum update.

Answer (score 36):

Faced same problem while installing jenkins on aws ec2 instance.
Below commands worked for me.

1. `sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y`
2. `sudo yum update -y`
3. `sudo yum install jenkins java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`

Reference JIRA ticket : https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66361

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: After lot of research find above solution

Comment: This worked. Thansk!

Comment: this works, but $sudo yum install jenkins -y works for the 3rd step if using a different jdk

Comment: @Geyser14 yes... in this answer i specifically used open jdk

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same issue while configuring jenkins.

As epel was already present but it was not enabled causing the issue
I installed and enable epel as

```
# sudo yum install epel-release -y 
# sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
# sudo yum install daemonize -y
```

then jenkins from - https://archives.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.io.key
```

If you've previously imported the key from Jenkins, the rpm --import will fail because you already have a key. Please ignore that and move on.

```
yum install jenkins
```

Comment: I can verify this works when using Amazon Linux 2018.03. I ran into certificate issues after the first three steps, which were that wget and rpm were incorrectly flagging certificates as expired. I fixed this by running `sudo yum update ca-certificates` per recommendations here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-expired-certificate/. However, Amazon Linux 2018.03 end of lifed in 2020 so the right option if you're in my position is to update to Amazon Linux 2

Answer (score 4):

Use this command:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue is reported on the Jenkins bug tracker:

https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66361

Note there are instructions on the bug report for installing from epel-release.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem with these two commands:

```
curl -LO 'https://rpmfind.net/linux/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/d/daemonize-1.7.7-1.el7.x86_64.rpm'
sudo rpm -Uvh ./daemonize-1.7.7-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install jenkins -y
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using AWS EC2 instance, below commands works

```
amazon-linux-extras install epel -y && yum update jenkins -y
```

https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66361?focusedCommentId=412263&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-412263