# Error while Installing Jenkins in Amzon Linux

Tags: jenkins, redhat, amazon-linux

when I install Jenkins in Amzon Linux, I get this error.
Not sure how to resolve, no details in internet.

```
[ec2-user@hostname ~]$ sudo yum install jenkins
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
jenkins                                                                                                           | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
jenkins/primary_db                                                                                                | 173 kB  00:00:00
45 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package jenkins.noarch 0:2.307-1.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: daemonize for package: jenkins-2.307-1.1.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: jenkins-2.307-1.1.noarch (jenkins)
           Requires: daemonize
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806741/how-to-fix-yum-update-of-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Just do it.

```
$ amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
```