# how to solve error during jenkins installation?

Tags: jenkins

I am getting this error while installing Jenkins which says "Error: Package: jenkins-2.308-1.1.noarch (Jenkins) Requires: daemonize". could someone help me out?

```
jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-11-26 08:45:36 UTC; 8ms ago
    Process: 20479 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 20479 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 122ms
```

Comment: 3rd this has been asked here recently. Tried searching ? [Error while Installing Jenkins in Amzon Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806741/how-to-fix-yum-update-of-jenkins)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix yum update of Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806741/how-to-fix-yum-update-of-jenkins)

Answer (score 13):

In order to solve this please install amazon epel repo and it should solve it by following below steps.

```
amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
```

```
Running transaction
  Installing : daemonize-1.7.7-1.el7.x86_64                                                                 1/3
  Installing : jenkins-2.303.1-1.1.noarch                                                                   2/3
  Installing : 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.302.b08-0.amzn2.0.1.x86_64                                  3/3
  Verifying  : daemonize-1.7.7-1.el7.x86_64                                                                 1/3
  Verifying  : jenkins-2.303.1-1.1.noarch                                                                   2/3
  Verifying  : 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.302.b08-0.amzn2.0.1.x86_64                                  3/3

Installed:
  java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 1:1.8.0.302.b08-0.amzn2.0.1            jenkins.noarch 0:2.303.1-1.1

Dependency Installed:
  daemonize.x86_64 0:1.7.7-1.el7
```

Answer (score 8):

Step1.

Create the YumRepo File.

```
vim /etc/yum.repos.d/epelfordaemonize.repo
```

```
[daemonize]
baseurl=https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/
gpgcheck=no
enabled=yes
```

**Step2**.

```
yum install daemonize -y
```

**Step3**.

```
yum install jenkins java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel -y
```

Comment: Finally an answer that does not assumes that I use an Amazon web server... Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Connect to your ec2 Instance

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
```

```
sudo vi vim /etc/yum.repos.d/epelfordaemonize.repo
```

```
    Add the following:
    [daemonize]
    baseurl=https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/
    gpgcheck=no
    enabled=yes
```

```
sudo yum install daemonize -y
```

```
sudo yum install jenkins java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel -y
```

```
service jenkins start
```

Use the ec2 public address x.x.x.x:port# to connect.
Admin password is in:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

file.
Note: You might have to modify the EC2 Security Group to allow external access
Note: You can modify which port Jenkins starts on in the:
/etc/sysconfig/jenkins ….. then restart Jenkins service

Answer (score 0):

Below commands worked for me.

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
```

```
sudo yum update -y
```

```
sudo yum install jenkins java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

Reference JIRA ticket : https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66361