# Jenkins installation on aws linux

Tags: jenkins, installation

getting below mentioned error :
Error: Package: jenkins-2.303.2-1.1.noarch (jenkins)
Requires: daemonize
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodiges

Comment: Something S/O for "(jenkins) Requires: daemonize" [returns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68806741/598141) [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68806741/598141) [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68915374/598141). You should not ask same.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing a pre-req that is not in the currently configured repos. I think if you just enable the EPL repo it will fix the problem or you can use the following steps https://marcelog.github.io/articles/install_daemon_tools_centos_amazon_linux.html

Answer (score 0):

This error represents the need dependency for the Jenkins server before the Jenkin please follow the below command.

#yum install epel-release -y

## yum install daemonize -y

Then you can continue on installing the Jenkins as

## yum install Jenkin -y

Answer (score 0):

Below commands worked for me.

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y 
sudo yum update -y 
sudo yum install jenkins java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

Reference JIRA ticket : https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66361